# How do SQL Server Permissions work when there are conflicting permissions?

Tags: sql-server

IE, if you are part of a Distribution Group that has READ ONLY access, but you are also part of a different Distribution Group that has UPDATE access, which will be the dominant permission?

Comment: This question appears to belong on [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What do you mean by a Distribution Group? In SQL Server, users can be members of database roles.

Answer (score 0):

You would have both permissions, reading tables / views and performing updates, yet no create or drop rights and so on.
As Andrew Morton stated, this belongs to Database Administration.

Comment: You should resist the temptation to write an answer to a question which belongs on another Stack Exchange site ;)

Comment: Didn't know about that, assumed administrators can move the question to the correct section. My apologies.